# How to handle querying across remote and cache data

Tags: breeze

Looking to find a good way to query across remote data and local cache simultaneously.  I need to be able to query remote data but merge the results with the local changes.

So if I add an item "Bob" and I get the first 5 results alphabetically ordered ascending, Instead of receiving "Aaron, Adam, Alice, Ashley, Bud", I would instead receive "Aaron, Adam, Alice, Ashley, Bob" and if I queried for the second 5 results (skip 5, take 5) the list would start with "Bud".  This also needs to handle deleting, so if I have locally deleted items 1 and 3 and I query for the first 50 items, I want to receive items 2 and 4 through 52.  And lastly queries for filtering need to address both the server and the local cache changes: so if I change "Sam"'s name to "Bob" and query for all names beginning with B, I should get Sam's new Bob record with Bill and the guys.

Normally we would just download all the rows with the initial query and allow for queryLocally to handle the work, but there is an issue because we are working with 10,000 records or more.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Frankly this is a very difficult problem ... much trickier than it seems at first. We solved it in DevForce with the [EntityQueryPager](http://drc.ideablade.com/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/query-paging). If you (and others) want this feature, please [vote for it on User Voice](http://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3438941-paged-query-combining-remote-and-cached-data).

Comment: Ward, my vote is in. Thank you for your response. This is exactly the solution that we require.

Comment: I don't want to raise your hopes too high. I'm glad you're voting for it. If it gets enough votes, we'll move it up the queue. We'd be happy to provide source of the DF component if someone wants to author a JS version before we can get to it. Let us know.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution to your scenario would be to query the server for "a little bit more" then expected as a result - but eventually always filter the local cache. Make the local cache the only source and filter/take/skip from it.

Now let's try to define what means "a little bit more".

> if I change "Sam"'s name to "Bob" and query for all names beginning with B, I should get Sam's new Bob record with Bill and the guys.

This should just work as you expect - no need to fetch more then "names beginning with B" from the server.

> if I add an item "Bob" and I get the first 5 results alphabetically ordered ascending, Instead of receiving "Aaron, Adam, Alice, Ashley, Bud", I would instead receive "Aaron, Adam, Alice, Ashley, Bob" and if I queried for the second 5 results (skip 5, take 5) the list would start with "Bud".

For this to work you will need to fetch remotely like this: **take** `numberOfEntitiesChangedLocally + ( pageNr * recordsPerPage )` and then skip and take from the local cache locally in the usual way.

Comment: Pawel, Thank you for your response.  I have been testing these scenarios with the Sample available in NuGet and I've found that some of your assumptions are not the case.  For example: if I have 4 items and 1 is set to IsDone on the checklist and I query for IsDone == true, I will get 1 result.  If I locally change a second item to IsDone, the Query still will only give me 1 result; which creates an issue with determining what SHOULD have been included in the query from the local cache. This is a bigger issue than the inverse (which happens as well) where a query on IsDone == false returns 3.

Comment: The result of the server-query will contain only one entity - that's ok. When this one entity is fetched (into the local cache) you should get two entities from the local-query. You should execute two queries - first remote query (ignore the results), next local query which should return what you expect.

Comment: A problem I've run into with this solution is that if I grab page 1 and then I jump to page 3, the local cache will only think there are 2 pages of data instead of 3.  I'd rather avoid querying for pages 1 to (n - 1) in order to properly query the local cache fore records.

Comment: I see what you mean. When user selects to view the last of 1000 pages we need to fetch all (possibly 20000) records - something you want to avoid. Try to rethink the business rules of the specific app you are writing. Maybe you will find a better algorithm for paging? Or maybe you can accept fetching the absolute minimum of data representing the information required for paging? For example you may fetch the Id and the field_used_for_orderBy of all records and then use this information on the client to calculate (including pending local changes) which Ids belong to page n.

Answer (score 0):

There are three examples of combined remote + local queries located in the \Samples\DocCode. Perhaps they will help.

Comments added here. The full code is in queryTests.js

1.
        * Combine remote and local query to get all customers 
        * including new, unsaved customers
        * v1 - Using FetchStrategy

2.
        * Combine remote and local query to get all customers 
        * including new, unsaved customers
        * v1=using FetchStrategy.FromLocalCache

3.
        * Combine remote and local query to get all customers 
        * including new, unsaved customers
        * v2=using ExecuteLocally()

An an interesting example of how not to do it anymore might interest you as well (also in queryTests:

```
    /*********************************************************************
    * This portion of the "queryTests (by id)" module  
    * tests a hand-built async getById utility that was the way to do it 
    * before EntityManager.fetchEntityByKey
    * A curiosity now.
    ********************************************************************/

    // This hand-built async getById utility method returns a promise.
    // A successful promise returns the entity if found in cache 
    // or if found remotely.
    // Returns null if not found or if found in cache but is marked deleted.
    // Caller should check for query failure.
    // 'queryResult' reports if queried the remote service 
    // and holds a found entity even if it is marked for deletion.
    // 
    // This fnc has been replaced by EntityManager.getEntityByKey.
```

Comment: Those are examples of combining Remote and Local but they fetch the entire set from the server. In this case, Jonneh cannot fetch the entire set so the examples don't apply and won't solve his problem.

Answer (score 0):

This must be achievable in java script, silver light is able to do that somebody might need to see how it is done is silver light and port it to java script.

I think logic should be when a switch is set(AlwaysRefreshDataOnQuery =false), then skip,overwriting the rows that has been modified(including deletes) otherwise simply clear the local cache and refresh it with new Data.

Silver light has been very powerful platform, i have not seen any platform to date as powerful as silver light(at least in .NET world).